# Regex for extracting word-number pairs with simple separators

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to find a regex that does the following. Let's say I have a string in this form

```
wordcount = "THE:12 IT:3 TO:3".
```

which is a word and its frequency. I need a regex that can find for example `THe`, followed by `:`, followed by a number.

Comment: What have you tried? You can have a play with Ruby regexes at http://rubular.com/ - it may help speed up the search

Comment: also, not every string manipulation needs to be regexp. wordcount.split.map{|x|x.split(':')} will also work to organize your code.

Comment: There isn't any `THe` in your string example.

Answer (score 5):

If you want all matches use the scan method:

```
mystring.scan(/\w+:\d+/)
```

Bonus if you are planning to make a hash:

```
Hash[mystring.scan(/(\w+):(\d+)/)]
# or, if you prefer to not use regexp:
Hash[x.split.map{|y| y.split(':')}]
```

Comment: This does not return a HASH

Comment: The second line do return a hash. p Hash[mystring.scan(/(\w+):(\d+)/)].class # => Hash

Comment: THe length of the hash is 0

Comment: Well, the size of the hash depends on the content of the variable mystring if i set mystring to "THE:12 IT:3 TO:3" i get a hash with 3 items.

Comment: For some reason ,That does not work for me.

Comment: Do you get a nested list from mystring.scan(/(\w+):(\d+)/) ? Maybe you are using an older version of Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below :

```
s = "THE:12 IT:3 TO:3"
p s.scan(/\w+:\d+/)
# >> ["THE:12", "IT:3", "TO:3"]
```